# Find mean of truncated normal distribution in R

Tags: python, r, statistics, normal-distribution, truncated

How can I find the mean of a truncated normal distribution in R, where the lower bound `a` is 1, `sigma` is 2, and `mu` is 2.5? I have used the `truncnorm` library, but it does not have any functions for moments. In Python, I tried the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
a, b = 1, np.inf
mean, var, skew, kurt = truncnorm.stats(a, b, moments='mvsk')
print(mean)
```

which gives `mean = 1.52513528`. How can I achieve the same result in R?

Comment: Hi @user2554330, the doc usage stated that `etruncnorm(a=-Inf, b=Inf, mean=0, sd=1) ` isn't mean already specified in the function? I cannot seem to find other resources on `etruncnorm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your python code, you are not setting location and scale and thus taking the default values for location = 0 and scale = 1. Thats why you get 1.525. You should consider the following:

Your example in python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
a, b = 1, np.inf
mean, var, skew, kurt = truncnorm.stats(a, b, moments='mvsk')
print(mean)
1.525135276160982
```

In R you could simply do:

```
a <- 1
b <- Inf
diff(dnorm(c(b, a)))/diff(pnorm(c(a,b)))
[1] 1.525135

truncnorm::etruncnorm(a, b)
[1] 1.525135
```

To make use of the provided data:

**Python**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
a, b = 1, np.inf
mu, sigma = 2.5, 2
mean, var= truncnorm.stats((a-mu)/sigma, (b - mu)/sigma, mu, sigma)
print(mean)
3.278764113471854
```

In R you can write a simple code to compute the mean:

```
truncnorm::etruncnorm(a, b, mu, sigma)
[1] 3.278764
```

You can always confirm your answer using base R:

```
qnorm(pnorm(diff(dnorm(c(b, a), mu, sigma))/diff(pnorm(c(a,b), mu, sigma))), mu, sigma^2)
[1] 3.278764
```